# For what value of k, $x^{2} + 2(k-1)x + k+5$ has at least one positive root?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots, quadratics

For what value of k,  $x^{2} + 2(k-1)x + k+5$ has at least one positive root?

**Approach: Case I :** Only $1$ positive root, this implies $0$ lies between the roots, so $$f(0)<0$$ and $$D > 0$$

**Case II:** Both roots positive. It implies $0$ lies behind both the roots. So, $$f(0)>0$$
$$D≥0$$
Also, abscissa of vertex $> 0  $

I did the calculation and found the intersection but its not correct. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Hint: Consider $(x+(k-1))^{2}$

Comment: It would be useful if you showed your working a bit more - what calculation you did and what you got.

Comment: Sir, I was getting $(-5, 1]$ but messed up after that, nevertheless, its all clear now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You only care about the larger of the two roots - the sign of the smaller root is irrelevant.  So apply the quadratic formula to get the larger root only, which is 
$\frac{-2(k-1)+\sqrt{4(k-1)^2-4(k+5)}}{2} = -k+1+\sqrt{k^2-3k-4}$.  You need the part inside the square root to be $\geq 0$, so $k$ must be $\geq 4$ or $\leq -1$.  Now, if $k\geq 4$, then to have $-k+1+\sqrt{k^2-3k-4}>0$, you require $k^2-2k-4> (k-1)^2$, which is a contradiction.  Alternately, if $k\leq -1$, then $-k+1+\sqrt{k^2-3k-4}$ must be positive, as required.

So you get the required result whenever $k\leq -1$.

Answer (score 3):

The [roots](http://tinyurl.com/d4e8dqj) are given by $1-k\pm\sqrt{k^2-3k-4}$, for which we have:
$$\cases{
1 - k + \sqrt{k^2 - 3k - 4} > 0 & if $\phantom{~-5< \;}k \le -1$\\
1 - k - \sqrt{k^2 - 3k - 4} > 0 & if $~-5<k\le -1 $.
}
$$
Wolfram Alpha gives the [plus](http://tinyurl.com/ccat3t2) and 
[subtract](http://tinyurl.com/ccyg39c) cases. So for $k\le -1$, you get at least one positive root.

Comment: For some of your $k$-values, the roots are not real (a fortiori, not positive). E.g., $k=0$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson true since $D=4k^2-12k-16<0$...but I think that's not what you are pointing at...?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $x_{1}$ is a real root, then we have that:

$$ (x_{1}+(k-1))^{2} - (k^2-3k-4) = 0 $$
$$(x_{1}+(k-1))^{2} = (k^2-3k-4)$$
$$(k^2-3k-4) \ge 0$$

It's obviously seen that the positive roots are got only when $k \le -1$.

Q.E.D.

Answer (score 1):

Another idea is the following, as the other answers mentioned, in order for the discriminant to be non negative you need $k \in (-\infty,-1] \cup [4,+\infty)$.

Now let $x_{1},x_{2}$ be the roots of the equation.

Case 1: $k \in (-\infty,-1]$ then you have that:

$$ x_{1}+x_{2} = -2(k-1) > 0 $$

And at least one of the roots must be positive.

Case 2: $k \in [4, \infty)$ we have that:

$$ x_{1} x_{2} = k+5 > 0 $$

Hence the roots must have the same sign. Furthermore as $x_{1}+x_{2}=-2(k-1) <0 $ so both of the roots must be negative. Thus $k \in (-\infty, -1 ]$ .